# How to add a new column to Python Pandas DataFrame and this new column has a value from another column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched stackoverflow for answers to my problem but even though some problems are close, this one has a different angle.

I have a dataset with various columns as below:

```
    date       next_workday    value1    value2     value3  
0   06/06/18   06/07/18        x         a          4.66
1   06/06/18   06/07/18        y         a          3.23
2   06/06/18   06/07/18        z         b          5.43
3   06/05/18   06/06/18        x         a          2.56
4   06/05/18   06/06/18        y         a          4.98
5   06/05/18   06/06/18        z         a          8.99
```

As you can see, there are a number of entries for the same day. In this case, three from 06/06/18 and three from 06/05/18. Now I want to add a new column (let´s call this value4) and this new column´s value should be from the value3-column meeting several conditions:

Look up the value3 for date= next_workday and take this value3 if value1 and value2 are the same as for the current day. Else value4 = vavlue3 from the current day.

So the final dataset should look like this:

```
    date       next_workday    value1    value2     value3    value4
0   06/06/18   06/07/18        x         a          4.66      4.66
1   06/06/18   06/07/18        y         a          3.23      3.23
2   06/06/18   06/07/18        z         b          5.43      5.43
3   06/05/18   06/06/18        x         a          2.56      4.66
4   06/05/18   06/06/18        y         a          4.98      3.23
5   06/05/18   06/06/18        z         a          8.99      8.99
```

So, for example, take row 4: It´s 06/05/18 ... the next_workday ist 06/06/18 .... value1 should be "y" and value2 should be "a" ... go to row 0, date=next_workday but value1="x" and not "y". Go to row 1, date=next_workday, value1 and value2 conditions are satisfied, therefore value4 is 3.23

How do I accomplish this with Pandas?

Comment: You should do this in two passes. First, just set all value4 = value3, then on those that satisfy your condition, replace them with the appropriate values. Doing it in separate passes makes the problem manageable.